# Hide row on checkbox specyfic column and word datatables

Tags: datatables

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
          
      var checked = $('input:checkbox[name="chk_box"]').is(':checked');
            
      // If checked and Position column is blank don't display the row
      if (checked &&searchData[1] ==='druk') {
        return false;
      }

      // Otherwise display the row
      return true;
          
    });
```

Is it possible to hide a row after searching for a specific string? I have this function, now it is looking for the exact word and how to make it look for the string:

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "_it is looking for the exact word and how to make it look for the string_"? Can you provide some data to show an example?

Comment: Now he hides a rows with only the word "druk". I can't do it so that it hides a rows with a sequence of characters, e.g. "abcdruk" 
<div class="formRight">
            <label>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk_box"  checked /> hide</label>
        </div>
<table>    
<tbody>
        <tr class="line">
            <td>druk1234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="line">
            <td>abcd</td>
        </tr>
       <tr class="line">
            <td>abcdruk</td>
        </tr
               </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: Please can you add your clarification to the question, instead of in a comment?

Comment: Also, how can you un-hide a row, after it has been hidden? Does your code do that? When I try to use your code, I can never see a row again after it has been hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that:Now he hides a rows with only the word "druk". I can't do it so that it hides a rows with a sequence of characters, e.g. "abcdruk"

```html
 <div class="formRight"> <label> <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk_box" checked /> hide</label> </div> <table> <tbody> <tr class="line"> <td>druk1234</td> </tr> <tr class="line"> <td>abcd</td> </tr> <tr class="line"> <td>abcdruk</td> </tr </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

I tried to use the includes function for example,but I don't know how to apply it to my example:

```js
const s1 = 'javascript';
const s2 = 'python';

console.log(s1.includes('script')); // true
console.log(s2.includes('script')); // false
console.log(s1.contains('java'))    // ERROR! .contains is not a function
```